# Why does the section overlap the navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

The section content is overlapping the navbar on certain screen sizes. I'm wondering why it's doing that and how to prevent it. Do I need to wrap everything in a container or what's the solution to this problem?

Using bootstrap v5.3.0-alpha1

also if i have a collapsed navbar, the button can't be pressed bc the section is overlapping it, so fixing this would be helpful

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>test</title>

        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/dashboard.css') }}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar bg-body-tertiary">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src={{url_for('static', filename='/images/logo.png')}} id="logo" alt="Logo" width="50" height="50" class="d-inline-block align-text-top" style="border-radius: 5px;">
                </a>

                <div class="btn-toolbar align-items-center justify-content-center" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
                    <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="sign in">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <!-- dropdown-toggle -->
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="connect_wallet_button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                Sign In
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end d-none" id="dropdown_menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="logout_button">Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="theme button">
                        <a href="/#">
                            <i class="bi bi-sun" id="theme_icon" style="font-size: 1.3rem;"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle p-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title text-center">test form</h3>

                    <form class="needs-validation" id="form" action="/form" method="post">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="test" value="False" name="test" required>
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="test">
                                    ???
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="d-none" id="form_button_group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="clear_button">Clear</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_button">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/dashboard.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.2.umd.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This setup has a number of issues and I wasn't sure which you wanted to address.  If all you're wanting to know is how to adjust what's on top, it's the z-index setting.  You can style your  element with [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to control what is displayed on top. I added a foreground class in your code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<style>
    .foreground {
        z-index: 50;
    }
</style>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>test</title>

        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/dashboard.css') }}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar bg-body-tertiary foreground">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src={{url_for('static', filename='/images/logo.png')}} id="logo" alt="Logo" width="50" height="50" class="d-inline-block align-text-top" style="border-radius: 5px;">
                </a>

                <div class="btn-toolbar align-items-center justify-content-center" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
                    <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="sign in">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <!-- dropdown-toggle -->
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="connect_wallet_button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                Sign In
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end d-none" id="dropdown_menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="logout_button">Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="theme button">
                        <a href="/#">
                            <i class="bi bi-sun" id="theme_icon" style="font-size: 1.3rem;"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle p-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title text-center">test form</h3>

                    <form class="needs-validation" id="form" action="/form" method="post">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="test" value="False" name="test" required>
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="test">
                                    ???
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="d-none" id="form_button_group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="clear_button">Clear</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_button">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/dashboard.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.2.umd.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: idk if this really addresses the issue. if part of the form is now being hidden under the navbar then it's still a problem...ideally the section would stop right under the navbar and not overlap it. edit: what are the other issues?

Comment: Nope, those are the same issues I was talking about. The position utility in bootstrap may not fit all of your needs and you may have to add a few @media queries to make your code responsive. I thought the question was a general one about overlapping. You may want to clarify the question.

Comment: Also, this utility's manual states "Quick positioning classes are available, though they are not responsive."  It's on you to make the code responsive through style sheets. If you post what you've tried to make it responsive in a new question, I would be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that your test form "div" is positioned with `absolute` causing **it to be removed from the normal document flow**. As a result, the top position is recalculated according to it's `top: 50% !important` rule, when the screen height is smaller or larger, leading to an overlay with the navbar or leaving lots of white space between the two elements.

To address this, I suggest removing the position rule and specifying a width for the test form "div" (I'm using `.container` here, you can change it to whatever fits your design). Additionally, add some margin for the navbar:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>test</title>

    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/dashboard.css') }}"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar mb-4 bg-body-tertiary">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src={{url_for('static', filename='/images/logo.png')}} id="logo"
          alt="Logo" width="50" height="50" class="d-inline-block
          align-text-top" style="border-radius: 5px;">
        </a>

        <div
          class="btn-toolbar align-items-center justify-content-center"
          role="toolbar"
          aria-label="Toolbar with button groups"
        >
          <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="sign in">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <!-- dropdown-toggle -->
              <button
                class="btn btn-primary"
                id="connect_wallet_button"
                type="button"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Sign In
              </button>
              <ul
                class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end d-none"
                id="dropdown_menu"
              >
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="logout_button"
                    >Logout</a
                  >
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="theme button">
            <a href="/#">
              <i
                class="bi bi-sun"
                id="theme_icon"
                style="font-size: 1.3rem"
              ></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title text-center">test form</h3>

          <form class="needs-validation" id="form" action="/form" method="post">
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="name"
                name="name"
                required
              />
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="name"
                name="name"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="name"
                name="name"
                required
              />
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="name"
                name="name"
                required
              />
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="name"
                name="name"
                required
              />
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="name"
                name="name"
                required
              />
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="name" class="form-label">test</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="name"
                name="name"
                required
              />
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <div class="form-check">
                <input
                  class="form-check-input"
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="test"
                  value="False"
                  name="test"
                  required
                />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="test"> ??? </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="d-none" id="form_button_group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="clear_button">
                Clear
              </button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_button">
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/dashboard.js') }}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="application/javascript"
      src="https://cdn.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.2.umd.min.js"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: appreciate it. how would i center it now if i can't use bootstraps 'position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle' class positioning?

Comment: You can run my example code, it's already centered horizontally with the help of the `.container` class

Comment: what about vertically too though? the bootstrap positioning class is nice because it makes it super easy, just not easy when it comes to responsiveness i guess lol

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to achieve. Do you want a form to be centered both on the x and y axis and leave the navbar at the top? Or it should be included too? If you're trying to center the form in both axes, positioning, and flexbox can help you do so.

Comment: ya basically how i have it in the op - the form vertically + horizontally centered and the navbar at the top. the only problem i had with it was that the responsiveness was lacking on certain dimensions - the form overlapped the navbar which was from the absolute positioning as u said